# Updated kernel with dpkg but old kernel still in use

Tags: kernel, updates

I needed to update my systems kernel to the latest available version, so I executed

```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-37-generic
   sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.13.0-37*
```

Then I rebooted.

But `uname -r` still shows `3.13.0-37-generic`

And theres no way I can update the kernels.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not install kernel, only headers.

If you want to upgrade kernel to 3.16 on Ubuntu 14.04 the correct way is this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

The meta package will pull both headers and image. 
This way kernels will be upgraded through routine process.